# Post Request in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm creating a pipeline in ADF that sends a post request, but it's returning the attached error.
Could you help what I might be doing wrong?
Below I put the code generated in the ADF for the post and the image with the error to facilitate the help.
What am I doing wrong, I can't identify my mistake.
Thank you all.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNsfH.png)

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbLUD.png)

I created the Web pipeline with the code below and it returned an error.

```
{

    "name": "xxxx_xxxx",

    "type": "WebActivity",

    "dependsOn": [],

    "policy": {

        "timeout": "0.12:00:00",

        "retry": 0,

        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,

        "secureOutput": false,

        "secureInput": false

    },

    "userProperties": [],

    "typeProperties": {

        "url": "https://xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx",

        "connectVia": {

            "referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",

            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"

        },

        "method": "POST",

        "body": {

            "fornecedor": "string",

            "tipoArquivo": "string",

            "data": [

                {

                    "id": 0,

                    "placa": "string",

                    "rastreadorNumeroSerie": "string",

                    "tipoEvento": "string",

                    "tempo": 0,

                    "rastreadorBateriaInternaAtiva": 0,

                    "rastreadorBateriaInternaTensao": 0,

                    "dataHoraEvento": "2022-12-24T14:23:14.865Z",

                    "gpsFixado": 0,

                    "latitudeInicio": 0,

                    "longitudeInicio": 0,

                    "latitudeFim": 0,

                    "longitudeFim": 0,

                    "velocidade": 0,

                    "altitude": 0,

                    "odometro": 0,

                    "bateriaExternaAtiva": 0,

                    "bateriaExternaTensao": 0,

                    "ignicao": 0,

                    "revGeoLogradouro": "string",

                    "revGeoFaixaNumeracao": "string",

                    "revGeoCep": "string",

                    "revGeoMunicipio": "string",

                    "revGeoUf": "string",

                    "horimetro": 0,

                    "sleep": 0,

                    "rpm": 0

                }

            ]

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: did you very all possible cause that are mentioned in the error? Like: 1) network connectivity and/or DNS failure: is `https://191.232.76.217/ituran/save`   2) Is the certificate OK, and valid?

Comment: I already found out, it was https, I changed it to http and it worked.